# Getting a Rainbow HAT working on a Banana Pi BPI-M2-Ultra

Tags: kernel

The Banana Banana Pi BPI-M2-Ultra has the same pin header layout as the Raspberry Pi, but runs Armbian. How do you setup the Rainbow HAT using Armbian's overlay system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

after 'sudo armbian-config', enable all I2C and SPI, I found the address

it is channel 2

> Blockquote pi@bananapim2ultra:~$ sudo /sbin/i2cdetect -y 2
> 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
> 00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
> 70: 70 -- -- -- -- -- -- 77

pi@bananapim2ultra:~$ ls -l /dev/spi*

crw------- 1 root root 153, 0 May 28 10:23 /dev/spidev0.0

crw------- 1 root root 153, 1 May 28 10:23 /dev/spidev1.0

in the end it came to an end with python:

in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rainbowhat

RPi.GPIO
PyExc_RuntimeError, "This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi!");

so I had to swap SBC Banana Pi BPI-M2-Berry to rpi3

Thanks